# How do I rigorously compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} a^x$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, indeterminate-forms

How do I rigorously compute $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} a^x$$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

I can intuitively and graphically get the answer of $\delta_{a\neq0}$ (Kroenecker delta), and I think also by using the $(\delta, \epsilon)$ definition, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it hand-wavely or rigorously.

UPDATE: the reason I am asking is because I'm thinking about teaching in statistics about median, mean, and mode, and how these quantities minimize a sum of distances $d_n(x−m)=|x−m|^n$, where for $n=2$ you get the mean, for $n=1$ you get the median, and, under this definition above, for $lim_{n\rightarrow0}$ you get the mode; but I wanted to make sure my math is rigorous in case I get fielded questions from students.

Comment: In real analysis, the function $a^x$ is commonly defined only when $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$. If you want to say anything "rigorously" about the limit, you need a rigorous *definition* of the function.

Comment: @user1046533 Is there a reason to treat $a = 1$ as a special case (aside from defining logarithms)?

Comment: @TheoBendit: Well, it is probably quite boring to write $1^x=e^{x\ln(1)}=1$ and this case does not have an inverse (as you mention about logarithms). Though, admittedly people may want to include this case for the convenience of some statements.

Comment: @user1046533 Ah OK, that makes sense. And if I were to *enrich* the standard real analysis definition with $0^x=\delta_{x=0}$, would I now have the rigorous definition necessary to answer my question? And so I guess my question would now become: How do you rigorously compute the limit of the Kroenecker delta -- would the standard way be via a $(\delta, \epsilon)$ proof? Since the limit for $a\neq0$ can be evaluated by direct substitution ... ?

Comment: The exponential function $a^x$, [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), and [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), they are all *different* things. Which one exactly are you asking?

Comment: @user1046533 I was originally using the high school definition of exponentiation $a^x$ that is also defined for $a=0$. Since you pointed out that in real analysis the definition of exponentiation does not include $a=0$ and therefore the operation is left undefined for that value, I have defined a new operation by enriching the real analysis definition by adding a behavior for $a=0$.

Comment: @user1046533 In particular, FYI the reason I am asking is because I'm thinking about teaching in statistics about median, mean, and mode, and how these quantities minimize a sum of distances $d_n(x-m) = |x-m|^n$, where for $n=2$ you get the mean, for $n=1$ you get the median, and, under this definition above, for $lim_{n\rightarrow0}$ you get the mode; but I wanted to make sure my math is rigorous in case I get fielded questions from students :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another consideration is to use $a^x = e^{x \, \ln(a)}$ and
$$ e^{t} = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3}{3!} + \cdots $$
to obtain the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \, a^{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \, e^{x \, \ln(a)} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(1 + x \, \ln(a) + \frac{x^2 \, \ln^{2}(a)}{2!} + \frac{x^3 \, \ln^{3}(a)}{3!} + \mathcal{O}(x^4) \right) \\
&= 1
\end{align}
for $a>0$. In the case $a$ is negative, say $a = -|b|$, then $\ln(a) = \ln(e^{\pi i} \, |b|) = \ln(|b|) + i \, \pi$ and leads to the same limiting result. The remaining case of $a = 0$ can also be considered and the $(\delta, \epsilon)$ definitions could also be applied.